# SSH into server and rsync from there – with non-standard port

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have two servers with non-standard ssh ports:

- liveserver.com -p 123
- testserver.com -p 456

To sync data from liveserver to testserver, I thought I'd ssh into testserver and rsync the data to local (aka testserver) from there.

```
ssh user@testserver.com -p 456 rsync -zra -e "ssh -p 123 --delete --exclude='.env' user@liveserver.com:/path/to/dump.bz2 path/to;
```

This gives me

```
Unexpected remote arg: user@liveserver.com:/path/to/dump.bz2
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1354) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Is my concept wrong or just the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh user@testserver.com -p 456 "rsync -zra -e 'ssh -p 123' --delete --exclude=.env user@liveserver.com:/path/to/dump.bz2 path/to"
```

not tested

Comment: Works! Thanks! Is it good practice to always use those double quotes or only when it breaks without them?

Comment: @Urs It's needed in this case because of what happens to that command before it gets executed. The local shell parses it, applying *and removing* the double-quotes. That's handed to the `ssh` command, which sends it to the remote computer where it's parsed *again* by a shell on that computer, which again applies and removes the single-quotes, and hands the result to `rsync` on that system. Since the single-quotes are the ones that apply to what's passed to `rsync`, they're really the ones that matter; but the double-quotes are still needed so the local shell doesn't remove the singles.

Comment: Handy trick for understanding the extra parsing step: replace the `ssh user@testserver.com -p 456` with `echo`, and see what it prints. That is what it looks like after the local shell has parsed and removed the first level of quotes (the double-quotes), and that's what'll be sent to the remote shell to be executed. If you can get that to be a valid command to execute on the remote system, then it should work when you put the `ssh...` part back.